# designing a circuit that accepts n 1-bit inputs and adds them

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design

In my Digital System design course, there is a recurring question in exams that I can't manage to know how to tackle.

You are given the design of a half-adder that accepts two 1-bit inputs and adds them.

You are also given the design of full-adder.

You are asked to cascade several of these adders to design a circuit that accepts n 1-bit inputs (for example 9 1-bit inputs) and adds them.

Any way I could figure out how to think about this type of problem?

Comment: Hint: `a+b+c+d = ((a+b)+c)+d`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single bit full adder can be seen as adding three one bit numbers to produce a 2 bit number. So that takes us from 9 1 bit numbers to 3 two bit numbers.

By carry chaining a half adder to a full adder we can produce an adder that adds two two bit numbers and produces a three bit number.

I'll leave you to figure out the final step....